# como importar un proyecto angular desde github

Tags: javascript, nodejs, typescript, angular11

quiero importar un proyecto de angular 11 pero no se como importarle, sin tener que copiar todos los componentes

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! que significaria importar? y a donde?

Comment: A este punto, lectura obligatoria https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822 Lean por favor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debes tener instalado en tu maquina dos herramientas:

- Git
- NPM (es el gestor de paquetes)

Para clonar el repositorio desde GitHub usas el comando `git clone`, y le pasas como parámetro la url del repositorio que deseas importar.

Ejemplo:

```
git clone https://github.com/jhondoe/Angular11.git
```

Una vez importado el proyecto te vas al interior de la carpeta del mismo, y ejecutas el comando `npm install`. Esto descargara todas las dependencias necesarias.

Y por ultimo usas el comando `npm start` para levantar el servidor. Si lo tienes predeterminado puedes ver el proyecto en el puerto 4200 como normalmente es.

Comment: gracias, una duda los comandos con `ng` por ejemplo `ng serve` o `ng generate` seguirán funcionado ?

Comment: @CristobalSilvestrebrito Es correcto, para la versión 11 de Angular siguen funcionando sus comandos `ng serve` y `ng generate`

Comment: Lo que estaria bueno explicarle a OP, mas alla que su pregunta es muy vaga, es que al hacer un git clone, esta copiando todos los componentes que necesita del proyecto... lo que pasa, es que lo hace por otro lado...

Comment: @gbianchi amigo solo tenia una duda para hacer una documentación, por cosas como esta stack esta categorizado como toxico

Comment: @CristobalSilvestrebrito me gustaria que me explicaras que te parecio lo toxico. Alguien adivino que era lo que preguntabas. Yo te deje un comentario pindiendo que explicaras que era lo que necesitabas...